# Master-Detail Relationship to Quote Line Item

Tags: master-detail

I have a requirement to have a child object from a Quote Line Item. The organisations security settings require objects to be Private at an Org-Wide Defaults level, and to avoid creating multiple sharing rules for our different personas I was hoping to create a Master-Detail relationship to the Quote Line Item to inherent the sharing from there.

When attempting to create the Master-Detail field on the new Custom Object (via the CLI), the following error is thrown.

`Cannot add a master-detail relationship to a Lead, Product or User`

The team and I have looked through the documentation but can't see any restrictions listed from Salesforce around this, although we know that there are some restrictions for some other standard objects.

Has anyone encountered this before, or know where this limitation is documented?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: the relevant [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/relationships_among_objects.htm) describes your error message - however, it doesn't explicitly say anything about `QuoteItem`. However, that object, and `OrderItem` have other limitations based on my experience,